# Disable warning about explicitly initializing base constructor inside copy constructor of derived class

Tags: c++, g++, warnings

I'm using g++ version 4.2.1 with -Wextra enabled. I'm including a header from a library, and I keep getting the following warning about a class in the library, which is enabled by -Wextra (I've replaced the class's actual name with BaseClass):

```
warning: base class ‘class BaseClass’ should be explicitly initialized in the copy constructor
```

My question is: how can I disable this warning? For example, -Wextra also enables -Wuninitialized, but I can override that simple by passing -Wno-uninitialized as a compiler flag. Is there anything similar for the warning about the copy constructor? I wasn't able to find the answer in the g++ manpages or in any other forum posts.

Comment: Without seeing some sample code, how could anyone possibly know?

Comment: Note also that disabling a warning is rarely a good approach...

Comment: This warning is arguably unnecessary. If no base class constructor is given in the derived class's initialization list, then the default constructor is called. In this case, I know and understand this behavior, so I don't want this warning to be emitted (plus, it's in a library I'd rather not modify).

Comment: Also, this question is about compiler flags and how to toggle them on or off, so why would any code be necessary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html (search for `Wextra`) that is an inherent part of `-Wextra` and can't be disabled separately (e.g. it isn't listed separately by its own `-W` option).

It looks like the best you can do is either isolate the use of the library to one file on which you disable `-Wextra` or don't use `-Wextra` at all and individually enable all its components (from that link).

Answer (score 7):

Given:

```
class BaseClass
{
public:
    BaseClass();
    BaseClass(const BaseClass&);
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
public:
    DerivedClass(const DerivedClass&);
};
```

This copy constructor:

```
DerivedClass::DerivedClass(const DerivedClass& obj)
  // warning: no BaseClass initializer!
{
}
```

Really means the same as:

```
DerivedClass::DerivedClass(const DerivedClass& obj)
  // Default construct the base:
  : BaseClass()
{
}
```

You can put in a default-constructor initializer like the above if that's really what you mean, and the warning will go away.  But the compiler is suggesting that you might actually want this instead:

```
DerivedClass::DerivedClass(const DerivedClass& obj)
  // Copy construct the base:
  : BaseClass(obj)
{
}
```

Comment: Yup, that's right. But do you know of any way of disabling just that one warning while keeping all of the other warning turned on by -Wextra?

Comment: No, I don't.  This is a case where I would many times prefer fixing the code to disabling the warning.

Answer (score 3):

If it's not a real problem, and you can't change the library (I guess you can't or you'd have done so), you can disable warnings temporarily using the [GCC diagnostic pragma](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html).

Comment: Interesting. When I add -fdiagnostics-show-option to the compiler flags to show what option controls that warning, it just says -Wextra. Apparently, there's no way to individually control that warning outside of -Wextra. But I can turn off -Wextra only when the compiler is going through the library's header file by using the diagnostic pragmas. Thanks!