# warning: base class ‘A’ should be explicitly initialized in the copy constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, copy-constructor

I've got the following class-structure:

```
class A{
   A(){}
   A(const A& src){}
};

class B : virtual A {
   B():A(){}
   B(const B& src):A(src){}
};

class C : virtual A {
   C():A(){}
   C(const C& src):A(src){}
};
class D : virtual B, virtual C {
   D():B(),C(){}
   D(const D& src):B(src),C(src){}
};
```

This gives me the warning:

> In copy constructor ‘D’:
>
> warning: base class ‘A’ should be explicitly initialized in the copy
>   constructor

Which I dont unterstand.
The Copy -Constructor of D calls the `copy-ctor` of B which calls the `copy-ctor` of A.
Why does it want me to call the `copy-ctor` of A in D?

If I would do so, wouldnt the `copy-ctor` of A be called twice? Once called from B and once called from D.

Any input on this is much appreciated.

Comment: It would never be invoked twice. But I don't really get this either.

Comment: Show your _real_ testcase. Class definitions end in semicolons, and your constructors aren't _really_ `private`.

Comment: When I fix those problems, the snippet compiles: http://ideone.com/V3ygZ  So your problem is somewhere between your invalid C++ and the proper approach. Don't know where until we see the code you're _actually_ using.

Comment: I don't have any warning from VC10 and gcc after fixing your code...

Comment: Already answered? http://stackoverflow.com/q/4788695/1141095

Comment: what compiler are you using? MingGw compiles when you fix the code with semi's and public constructs.

Comment: Agreed. No warning with gcc after fixing code...

Comment: This doesn't even make sense. Class C *can't* directly initialize class A because it doesn't derive directly from class A. Show the real code!

Comment: If B inherits virtual from A then C would indeed be responsible for initializing A. Of course it would need access and it doesn't have it at present because B derives from A privately.

Comment: @CashCow yes, you are right. The problem was virtual inheritance. Thanks to all.

Comment: @veio: So why don't you just update your example such that others can learn from it?!

Comment: well, wanted to answer it, but was not allowed yesterday because of 8h rule..

Comment: @veio: But you've only just changed the question to expose a very different issue; you don't have to wait 8 hours to make clarifications to your own questions.

Answer (score 2):

Now I have confirmed that I was right, B used virtual inheritence to derive from A.

When that happens, the most derived class is responsible for constructing the base class. This allows the multiple inheritence diamond.

```
======== A ============
   ^            ^
   B            C
    \           /
     \         /
      \       /
       \     /
          D
```

D derives from B and C and both derive from A so D would inherit 2 copies of A, one from B and one from C.

If B1 and B2 both use virtual inheritence to derive from A, then the final class must initialize the base class, i.e. A, thus ensuring just once instance.

This is why you got the error message.

Answer (score 1):

> The Copy -Constructor of D calls the copy-ctor of B which calls the copy-ctor of A.

No, it doesn't. A virtual base class is *always* initialized by the most derived class being constructed. Initializations in member initializer lists for classes in the inheritance hierarchy that are not the most derived class for the object under construction are ignored. A virtual base class can only be initialized once and the rule is that the most derived class will do this either explicitly, or implicitly if the base class does not appear in the member initializer list of the most derived class constructor being used.

As the warning hints, for a copy constructor you almost certainly want to explicitly initialize the virtual base class from the object being copied.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the virtual inheritance. Because of that A should be initialized explicitly.