# warning: base class should be explictily initialized in the copy constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I'm writing a matrix class for CUDA processing.

I've written a vector class (henceforth known as `Elements`) and used that for the matrix base.

Here is the template definition:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t M, std::size_t N>
class Matrix : public Elements< Elements< T, N >, M > {

}
```

It should be noted that nothing is dynamically allocated in the `Elements` class, nor in the `Matrix` class.

I'm getting a `warning: base class ‘struct Elements<Elements<double, 2ul>, 2ul>’ should be explicitly initialized in the copy constructor` warning in the copy constructor. Here is the copy constructor:

```
    DEVICE HOST
    Matrix(const Matrix & that) {
        for (std::size_t ind = 0; ind < M; ind++) {
            for (std::size_t jnd = 0; jnd < N; jnd++) {
                (*this)[ind][jnd] = that[ind][jnd];
            }
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [warning: base class ‘A’ should be explicitly initialized in the copy constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098979/warning-base-class-a-should-be-explicitly-initialized-in-the-copy-constructor)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're not initializing the base class in the copy constructor. Try this:

```
Matrix(const Matrix & that) : Elements<Elements<T, N>, M>(that) {
    /* ... */
}
```

The initializer list of the derived class' copy constructor should contain an explicit call to the base class' copy constructor, just like with all other constructors, otherwise, the base class will be default-initialized.

**Edit:** It can be handy to have a private

```
typedef Elements<Elements<T, N>, M> basetype;
```

in your class definition somewhere.

Comment: @dyp: Thanks for spotting that - updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: It would be more flexible to use the template arguments when invoking Element's constructor, or this might only compile when using a Matrix templated with a double type.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I'm editing your answer to use `typename T` instead of double, explicitly. Otherwise, good show.

Answer (score 2):

For any derived class, the base class needs to be constructed whenever the derived class is. If your base class doesn't have a default ( 0 argument ) constructor, you will have to specify how to construct it in all of your derived class's constructors.

So, assuming Elements has a public copy constructor, you would need something like :

```
Matrix(const Matrix & that) 
: Elements<Elements<T, N>, M>(that)
{ 
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you explicitly define a copy constructor of a derived class and do not call in the ctor list the copy constructor of the base class then the compiler itself will call the default constructor for the base class. It is posiible that it is not what you wanted. So the compiler warns you.

I have an example that demonstrates the difference in my artical
["Implicitly defined copy constructor and explicitly defined copy constructor: what is the difference"](http://cpp.forum24.ru/?1-1-0-00000021-000-0-0-1388485669)
it is written in Russian but you will be able to read it using for example google service translate.