# Suppressing "Base class ‘class X’ should be explicitly initialized in the copy constructor" from library header for template class

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, compilation

I am having a problem similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788695/disable-warning-about-explicitly-initializing-base-constructor-inside-copy-const).

I am using a third party library. It defines classes as here (faked all the names due to licensing issues), in file `headers/things.h`:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual ~A() {}
};


template < class T, class U >
class B : virtual public A {
public:
    B(T) {}

    B(const B< T,U >) {}

    virtual ~B() {}
};


template < class T, class U >
class  C : virtual public B< T, U > {
public:
    C(T t) : B < T, U > (t) {}

    C(const C< T,U > &other) : B< T,U >(other) {}

    ~C() {}
};
```

Additionaly, still in the library header:

```
typedef C< int, int > CC;
```

The error message is:

```
cc1plus: warnings being treated as errors
../headers/things.h: In copy constructor ‘C<T, U>::C(const C<T, U>&) [with T = int, U = int]’:
things.cpp:5:   instantiated from here
../headers/things.h:22: warning: base class ‘class A’ should be explicitly initialized in the copy constructor
../headers/things.h: In copy constructor ‘B<T, U>::B(const B<T, U>&) [with T = int, U = int]’:
../headers/things.h:23:   instantiated from ‘C<T, U>::C(const C<T, U>&) [with T = int, U = int]’
things.cpp:5:   instantiated from here
../headers/things.h:12: warning: base class ‘class A’ should be explicitly initialized in the copy constructor
```

In `things.cpp`, I have:

```
#include "things.h"

CC make_cc() {
    CC cc(123);
    return cc;
}

int main() {
    CC cc = make_cc();
    return 0;
}
```

File layout is:

```
../
|-- source
|   `-- things.cpp
`-- headers
    `-- things.h
```

I am aware of what this warning means and I am not asking for that.
Since it is in a third party library, I am very reluctant to modify (fix) it for maintenence reasons. I simply want to ignore this warning.

I am compiling my code with:

```
g++ things.cpp -o things -Wall -Wextra -Werror -isystem ../headers/
```

I am using `-isystem` for specifying the directory, because the gcc docs state that:

> All warnings, other than those generated by ‘#warning’ (see Diagnostics), are suppressed while GCC is processing a system header.
>   (...)
>   The -isystem command line option adds its argument to the list of directories to search for headers, just like -I. Any headers found in that directory will be considered system headers.

This seems to work in general, as nearly all warnings from the third party library are indeed suppressed.

Unfortunately, as this declaration happens to be an instantiation of a `typedef`'d templated class, the compiler thinks that it is *my* code that it is compiling, not the (fake) system header.

As said in the referenced question, it is impossible to suppress this warning only, and I'd have to disable `-Wextra` instead, which I don't want to do.

*Question*: Is it possible to suppress this warning anyhow? To make gcc aware it's not my code, but the library code?

I am using gcc 4.1.2.

Comment: gcc-4.1.2 is 8 years old now, is that the version you have to use?  I tried your code sample with gcc-4.6, gcc-4.8, gcc-4.9 and clang++-3.4 and none of them had this warning.

Comment: The code you posted produces a lot of errors but not the warning you mention. Please build an MCVE that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately yes - the provider of the library (and framework in general) states that this is the only officially supported version of gcc for Linux. Same goes for the dialect, we use `gnu++98`.

Comment: @Wintermute I have edited the question, please have a look now.

Comment: What happens if you correct the header? Does the whole thing compile/link then?

Comment: Yes. If I correct the copy ctors by adding explicit call to default ctor of `A`, like this: `B(T) : A() {}`, `B(const B< T,U >&) : A() {}`, `C(T t) : A(), B < T, U > (t) {}`, `C(const C< T,U > &other) : A(), B< T,U >(other) {}` the warning is gone, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, using a newer compiler seems to be a better approach than the following, but as you're hands seem to be tied, consider the following approach:

Create wrapper classes around the third party library classes along the lines of

```
class MyCC {
    CC cc;
};

template<typename T, typename U>
class MyB {
    B<T, U> b;
};
```

Forward any relevant function calls to make the wrappers as transparent as you feel is necessary.
Alternatively you could use something like [BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/serialization/doc/strong_typedef.html).

The header(s) where these wrappers are defined could then have at the top of the a file:

```
#pragma GCC system_header
```

Hopefully that pragma will suppress the warning in the *only* client that uses the library directly, whereas all other code could then use the wrappers instead, thus not needing the pragma.

Comment: I am trying to implement the solution you've proposed. Please take a look here: http://pastebin.com/sGWLbPZ4, is this what you meant? I so, the #pragma doesn't seem to help, I'm still getting warnings: `../headers/things.hpp: In copy constructor ‘C<T, U>::C(const C<T, U>&) [with T = int, U = int]’:
../headers/x.hpp:28:   instantiated from here`

Comment: I meant placing the pragma before the including things.hpp. Can you check whether that solves the issue?

Comment: @Matthiias Vegh, I've checked it and it has no effect either.